# How can we enable window workflow foundation inside Dockerfile for window base images for building Dot Net Framework application?

Tags: powershell, msbuild, dockerfile, visual-studio-2022, workflow-foundation

**I am Facing the below error while building window-base Docker image for Dot Net Framework Application.**
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Xaml.targets(193,5):error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Xaml.PartialClassGenerationTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\XamlBuildTask.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\XamlBuildTask.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

Comment: Please make sure that workflow component is installed by Visual Studio by default in that folder https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/3956. Or make sure that if it uses the correct version.

Comment: But what will be in case of Dockerfile for window base image?

Comment: @HassanShamshir were you able to figure out how to fix the issue?